# ImportError: cannot import scipy from windows powershell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-2.7, scipy.spatial

I am having an importError message while trying to import scipy from powershell. But I am able to do this when I try to do this in the python shell in ArcGIS. 
The error I get is this:

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File stdin, line 1, in module 
ImportError: No module named scipy

While trying to import arcpy, numpy, gdal all works well. Can anyone help with the problem? I did search but could not find a similar problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your path variables?
PYTHONPATH should be set to C:\Python27\Lib and PYTHONHOME should be set to C:\Python27
(Or wherever your python install is located).

Also note that python is installed with ArcGIS, and it can cause confusion if you have more than one install of python.

Comment: Yes, I did check the PYTHONPATH.It is in C:\Python27|Arcgis10.2\lib etc..I just have one Python installed, the one comes with ArcGIS.